# Visualization of 3d scalar field in python

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, noise

I have scalar field defined on 3d grid: f(x_i, y_i, z_i), where x_i = 0, 1,.., 99; y_i = 0, 1,.., 99, z_i = 0, 1,.., 99. I want to visualize this as 3d noise in a 100x100x100 box ([example](https://forums.odforce.net/uploads/monthly_2018_02/visualize_noise_3d_volume.png.e66ff6fd75e9e4a97b3105c47bcf3ce9.png)). I tried to do it using matplotlib, but it doesn't allow. Is there a simple way to visualize this field in this form in python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to rewrite it more clearly. I have an array **A** with the shape (100, 100, 100), so A[5][15][97] is a value at a point with x = 5, y = 15, z = 97. I want to visualize this field in form of 3D fog. The more value, the less transparency. Tris allows us to see areas with a high value through areas with low value, because the last ones are almost transparent.